# LM4910 headphone amplifier noise source

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design, audio, noise, headphones

I built a headphone amplifier using the LM4910, following the typical application schematic in the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4910.pdf?ts=1663084164316&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F). The noise floor of this IC is specified at around 50uV for a 32 Ohm load, while my circuit (under the same conditions) produces very audible noise in the range of a few millivolts.

Measuring the left channel into a 47 Ohm resistor verified that the bandwidth is indeed limited to its minimum within the audible spectrum. The 47 kOhm resistors are likely not major noise contributors either, as the datasheet recommends values up to 1 MOhm. I tried powering the circuit using a lab power supply and batteries and increased the decoupling capacitances, all of which did not help.

What major sources of white noise am I missing here?

**Circuit**
[image]

**Bode Plot**
[image]

Comment: I think it's because the 50uV noise from the datasheet is the noise at specific frequencies, but the several mV you're measuring is the total noise in the spectrum.

Comment: That's about about 1mV RMS on each channel. Of course! I completely misread the noise floor figure in the datasheet. How would I calculate the RMS noise at the output then?

Comment: I guess they left out the \$\sqrt{\text{Hz}}\$ in the Y axis legend. It's also supposedly A-weighted which it doesn't look like- down by 20dB at 100Hz and 10dB at 20kHz.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I'm not sure the datasheet is wrong... If  they mean \$\frac{50uV}{\sqrt{Hz}}\$ that would result in \$50uV \cdot \sqrt{20kHz \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}} = 8.86 mV_{RMS}\$ noise for a bandwidth of 20kHz, which is way too high.